# MySql 5.6 event is not running, but other events are running

Tags: mysql, events

I have a MySql 5.6.10 database with the event scheduler enabled.

There are several events that are currently running successfully.  I disabled one event and then after enabling it again, i noticed that it wasn't running.  I tried disabling and enabling a few times, but still the event was not starting.  So, i dropped the event and recreated it.  That still didn't work, and the event will not run.

The event calls a stored procedure and I can manually run the CALL proc() that is in the event, and that works.

I created a test table and a test event to insert into that table, and that one doesn't work either.

Here is the test event i created:

```
CREATE EVENT test_event_01
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO  test_db.test_event_msg(message_text,createdDate)
          VALUES('Test MySQL Event 1',UTC_TIMESTAMP());

    END
```

Any thoughts or suggestions that I can try or check?

Thank for any help!

Comment: You shedule the event to be executed only one time. And the execution time is set to 1 minute after current datetime which (in scheduling properties) is the event creation (not enabling) time. So when you enable your event is sees that the time when it should be fired is a time in the past - and it is not fired. Recreate it - and it will fire once. Recreate it with `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE` - and it will fire each minute. In last case - it will fire each minute after disabling and further enabling.

Comment: thanks for the help.  But, I probably should have included my other event DDL.  That is what i had done. I had even re-created the event to Start at a future time (like 5 minutes into the future) and also with a scheduler every 1 minute.  But that still does not work.  The event just does not run.  Very weird.

Comment: There are no miracles. You did something wrongly. Check does ES is enabled, does the creator have enough permissions and so on.

Comment: yes.  all checked.... and still...the "miracle" persists!  :)  thanks for the suggestions. I'll just keep trying things.

Comment: I was finally able to figure out and resolve the issue.  
I turned out to be an error/issue with the event scheduler itself.  It was odd because all of the other events were running, but just the new ones that were created would not run at all.
I checked the mysql logs and in one of them I found some error messages that indicated an issue with the event scheduler.  I researched the error message, but could not find anything that matched.   I just ended up rebooting the server and that "fixed" the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the last comment, rebooting the MySQL instance resolved the issue with the event scheduler.